# regex for dot before optional word terminating numbers

Tags: python, regex, word-boundaries

A similar question has been asked here:

[Regex to match word bounded instances with 'dot' inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513559/regex-to-match-word-bounded-instances-with-dot-inside)

but in my opinion my question was not answered.

I want to look for numbers between word boundaries consisting of digits, a dot and optional digits (in Python):

```
import re    
search_in = '55.1 55. 55.12'
reg_str = r'\d+\.\d*\b'
lst = re.findall(reg_str, search_in)
print(lst) # ['55.1', '55.12']
# expected: ['55.1', '55.', '55.12']
```

If the dot is at the end of the word, there will be no match. Nor could I find out why it is so neither found a solution for it. Could anyone help please?

Comment: It's not necessary using regex, or you want to use regex?

Comment: Works if you remove the word boundary check from your regex; `\d+\.\d*`

Answer (score 0):

just remove `\b` (the word boundary) in your regex

```
import re
search_in = '55.1 55. 55.12'
reg_str = r'\d+\.\d*'
lst = re.findall(reg_str, search_in)
print(lst)
```

or you can use just `split()` function if you want to separate between spaces

```
search_in = '55.1 55. 55.12'
print(search_in.split(" "))
```

output 
`['55.1', '55.', '55.12']`

Comment: Yes, I know that without the word boundary it's easy. That's exactly why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` anchor represents word boundary meaning it would target the groups that are bounded by words instead of numbers, hence the middle number won't be captured since the next pattern is a number. The correct regex solution would be `\b\d+\.\d*`.

Comment: "bounded by words instead of numbers" - what does that mean?

Comment: Meaning, it cannot target the group `1234` in `abcd1234abcd` if the pattern was `\b\d*\b` but `\B` anchor can target the group `1234` in `abcd1234abcd` if the pattern was `\B\d*\B`. For more info, check out the cheatsheet in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com).